# Ubercart PayPal Error 15005

Tags: paypal, drupal-7, ubercart

I manage a web site running under Drupal 7.x and Ubercart 3.x
Credit card processing default gateway is PayPal Website Payments Pro.
Everything works, however I have been seeing some odd errors, and I'm not sure if it is something I need to worry about or not.
Over the past 30 days, this has happened 8 times, with 4 times occurring in the last week.

Orders paid by credit card return a PayPal error code 15005 one to three times, and then validates successfully. So it fails three times, and then works. I don't have enough rep to include a screenshot, but here is the copied text from the order view:

> Admin comments:
>   DATE    USER    COMMENT
>   09/14/2014 - 13:15  -   Authorize and capture immediately failed.
>   Error: 15005: This transaction cannot be processed.
>   09/14/2014 - 13:15  -   Authorize and capture immediately failed.
>   Error: 15005: This transaction cannot be processed.
>   09/14/2014 - 13:17  -   Authorize and capture immediately failed.
>   Error: 15005: This transaction cannot be processed.
>   09/14/2014 - 13:18  -   Authorize and capture immediately
>   Success: 41.90 USD
>   Address: Address and postal code matched
>   CVV2: Match
>   09/14/2014 - 13:18  -   Order created through website.

I know that the error code means:

> "The transaction was declined by the issuing bank, not PayPal. The
>   merchant should attempt another card."

Which is why this error is confusing to me.
Is it trying to process the card multiple times until it works?
Any idea what is going on here and does it need fixed?

Comment: Can you post the complete response for the declined transaction including the correlation id ?

Comment: @eshan This is the only other info recorded with the error and is the watchdog error: Payment failed for order 34063: <b>Authorize and capture immediately failed.</b><br /><b>Error:</b> 15005: This transaction cannot be processed.

Comment: I could ask the owner of the site/PayPal account for the unique transaction ID, if you work for PayPal and can assist me. But if that is the case, I would prefer to communicate with you through your PayPal contact details. @Eshan

Comment: Yes sure , You can go here www.paypal.com/mts and submit the ticket   there and paste me the ticket here so that we can communicate .

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out that this was all normal behavior due to customers entering incorrect credit card data. PayPal was able to look up the transactions and verify that this is a non-issue and expected responses due to customer input.